# MySQL how do I combine these tables?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I have three tables:

```
blog_posts
  int id (auto increment)
  varchar(255) title
  text content

blog_tags
  int id (auto increment)
  varchar(63) name

blog_posttags
  int id (auto increment)
  int post_id
  int tag_id
```

How can I get (preferably with as few as possibly queries) this data like a multidimensional array with the following structure?

I can figure out how to make the array from the database, but not how to get it done like this without making a query for every blogpost I receive to see which tags belong to it.

```
$blogposts = array(
    array(
        'id' => 0,
        'title' => 'blogpost title',
        'content' => 'blogpost content',
        'tags' => array(
            'tagname1', 'tagname2', 'tagname3', ...,
        )
    ),
    ... (multiple blogposts because WHERE condition may return more than 1)
)
```

I'd imagine I have to use `UNION` or `JOIN` or something like that, but I'm not really experienced with advanced MySQL statements.

Edit: You may assume that a `tag_id` in `blog_posttags` also exists in `blog_tags`, same goes with `post_id` and `blog_posts`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** get all the tags in a single query using MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function:

```
SELECT   a.id
        ,a.title
        ,a.content
        ,(      SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) 
                FROM    blog_tags b
                JOIN    blog_posttags c
                ON      b.id = c.tag_id
                WHERE   c.post_id = a.id
         ) AS tags
FROM    blog_posts a
```

will concatenate the tags like:

```
id  title       content         tags
-------------------------------------------
1   Blog 1      blah blah blah  funny,work 
2   Next Post   yadda yadda     school,work
```

which returns an array like this:

```
$blogposts = array(
    array(
        'id' => 0,
        'title' => 'blogpost title',
        'content' => 'blogpost content',
        'tags' => 'tagname1,tagname2,tagname3'
    ),
//etc
);
```

And then you just need to run a loop like this to split up the comma delimited tag string

```
foreach($blogposts as $k => $v){
    $blogposts[$k]['tags'] = explode(',', $v['tags']);
}
```

Here is sample [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f26f/2) with a couple dummy tags and posts I used to test this before posting

**Edit**

Here is an alternate way to achieve the same results without using a sub-query:

```
SELECT       a.id
            ,a.title
            ,a.content
            ,GROUP_CONCAT(c.name) AS tags
FROM        blog_posts a
JOIN        blog_posttags b
ON          a.id = b.post_id
JOIN        blog_tags c
ON          b.tag_id = c.id
GROUP BY    a.id
```

Comment: i like answers with SQL Fiddle examples +1

Comment: [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f26f/13/0) same as your answer above just easier to read (at least for me anyways).

Comment: hah that's funny I was working on the non-subquery example, looks pretty much the same as yours

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is exactly what I was looking for! Edit; Playing around with SQL Fiddle lets me understand it even better, thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Your basic query for getting the tags information matched up to the posts will look like.

```
Select bp.Id, bp.title, bp.content, bt.name 
from blog_posts bp
JOIN blog_posttags bpt ON bp.Post_id = bpt.post_id
JOIN blog_tags bt ON bt.tag_id = bpt.tag_id
```

This will get you multiple rows that each match up one post to one tag. Grouping the tags into an array isn't really something that you can do on the SQL side, but you can do

```
Select bt.name 
from blog_posts bp
JOIN blog_posttags bpt ON bp.Post_id = bpt.post_id
JOIN blog_tags bt ON bt.tag_id = bpt.tag_id
WHERE bp.Id = 12345
```

as a separate query to get the tags for a given post. Between these two, you should be able to create the nested array at an application level.