# Combining tables while searching for one of the elements

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I asked this question yesterday:

[MySQL how do I combine these tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230860/mysql-how-do-i-combine-these-tables)

I want to search blogposts by their tags, how do I do this?

Again, my tables are:

```
blog_posts
  int id (auto increment)
  varchar(255) title
  text content

blog_tags
  int id (auto increment)
  varchar(63) name

blog_posttags
  int id (auto increment)
  int post_id
  int tag_id
```

I currently have the following query for searching for a blogpost by it's tag, but I also want it's tags (like in my previous question).

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   blog_posts a,
       blog_tags b,
       blog_posttags c
WHERE  b.id = c.tag_id
       AND c.post_id = a.id
       AND b.name = "searchTag"
GROUP  BY a.id
```

But this obviously does not return any tags along with the blogpost info.

Can this be done in one query? Because there might be more than one blogpost with this tag, and I don't want to run queries for each blogpost to find their tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just combine your other query with this one. Try this:

```sql
SELECT   a.id
        ,a.title
        ,a.content
        ,(SELECT        GROUP_CONCAT(b.name) 
                FROM    blog_tags b
                JOIN    blog_posttags c
                ON      b.id = c.tag_id
                WHERE   c.post_id = a.id
         ) AS tags
FROM blog_posts a
INNER JOIN blog_posttags c ON c.post_id = a.id
INNER JOIN blog_tags b ON b.id = c.tag_id
WHERE b.name = "work"
GROUP BY a.id
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f26f/30)</kbd>